# For a von Neumann algebra, if the elements are all normal, then it is commutative.

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, normal-operator

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a von Neumann algebra, if the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are all normal, then $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative.

I want to know how to prove this, or where I can find the proof. Thank you.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an operator $T$, let $\Re(T)=(T+T^*)/2$ and $\Im(T)=(T-T^*)/(2i)$.  $\Re(T),\Im(T)$ are self-adjoint and $T=\Re(T)+i\Im(T)$.

Verify that $T$ is normal if and only if $\Re(T),\Im(T)$ commute.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a von-Neumann algebra.

If all self-adjoints in $\mathcal{A}$ commute then by the real-imaginary decomposition above, all members of $\mathcal{A}$ commute.

Otherwise, there are a couple of self-adjoints $P,Q\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $P$ and $Q$ don't commute.  Then $P+iQ$ is not normal.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.